# Angular 2 error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get this error when i compile

I don't find where I should add a comma.

```
src/app/navbar.component.ts(29,39): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/tache.service.ts(53,53): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
      add(name: string): void {
        name = name.trim();
        if (!name) { return; }
        this.tacheService.create(name)
        .then(tache => {
             this.tacheService.insert( tache: Tache); // the first error ( line 29)
        });
      }
```

**service.ts**

```
update(tache: Tache): Promise<Tache> {
        tache.stat = 1;
        return this.http
          .put(this.tachesUrl, JSON.stringify(tache.stat:1), {headers: this.headers}) // second error ( line 53 )
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => tache)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(tache.stat:1)` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can pass the data type with the argument:

```
this.tacheService.insert( tache: Tache);
```

should be

```
this.tacheService.insert( tache );
```

Comment: Indeed. `JSON.stringify(tache.stat:1)` is invalid syntax as well.

Comment: Indeed, you annotate types on *parameters* (and variables and...), not *arguments*.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.tacheService.insert( tache: Tache); // the first error ( line 29)
this.tacheService.insert( tache); // No Error
```

---

```
return this.http
    .put(this.tachesUrl, JSON.stringify(tache.stat:1), {
        headers: this.headers
    }) // second error ( line 53 )
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => tache)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

---

```
return this.http
    .put(this.tachesUrl, JSON.stringify(tache.stat), {
        headers: this.headers
    }) // No Error
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => tache)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```